# Hyperledger Composer updating particiapnt detail

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I am new to hyperledger composer and writing very basic code. I want to create a bna in which user can transact among themselves using token.

My Model.cto looks like

```
namespace org.acme.remittance

participant Member identified by id {
o String id
o String name
o String mobile
o Double balance
}



transaction Transfer {
  --> Member from
  --> Member to
  o Double val
}
```

and my logic.js looks like this:

```
async function transfer1(transferNew) {

  transferNew.from.balance -= transferNew.val;
  transferNew.to.balance += transferNew.val;

   let participantregitsry = await getParticipantRegistry('namespace org.acme.remittance.Member');
  await participantregitsry.updateAll([transferNew.from, transferNew.to]);
 }
```

I am able to successfully fire transaction but balance is not getting updated. Please help in finding out error in my code. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you have the decorators before your function - something like:

> ```
>  /**
>  * Track the trade of a commodity from one trader to another
>  * @param {org.acme.remittance.Transfer} transferNew - the trade to be processed
>  * @transaction
>  */
> ```

Then you need to remove the word `namespace` from the getParticipantRegistry  line e.g.

`let participantregitsry = await getParticipantRegistry('org.acme.remittance.Member');`

Then it should work as expected.

Comment: Oops!! I completely missed that and even composer did not show any error. Thanx!!